# Layout being ignored on AppHarbor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, appharbor

I have an MVC application that renders fine locally but when deployed to Appharbor it renders only the view portion of the page and ignores the layout.

Any ideas on possible causes?

I've tried enabling/disabling precompilation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that the `_ViewStart.cshtml` file was no longer a part of the project. Since the physical file was still there, local debugging was picking it up and was running fine.

However, without it being a part of the build, when AppHarbor built the project it wasn't included causing all the views (without an explicit Layout) to render with `Layout = null`

Thanks everyone! *facepalm*